# best practice to run db:create with kubernetes and minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am new to kubernetes and I am trying to setup a rails application using minikube.

I wanted to know whats the best practice to run setup tasks like rake `db:create` which we execute only once during the application setup.

I currently did it by executing

`kubectl exec pod_name rake db:create`

would this be a good practice to setup the database for the first time or is there a better or standard way to this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve the same result, by propagating `command:` field in the source manifest file, i.e:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ruby
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ruby
    image: ruby:2.5
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "rake db:create" ]
```

Reach out more information in the official k8s [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod), some hints explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976455/start-kubernetes-container-with-specific-command).