# How to run "--verbose" for wiremock in docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wiremock, sbt-docker-compose

I want to get verbose output from mockwire when running in docker using docker compose file.

I tried these three ways but none of them work.

first way

```
services:
   wiremock:
     image: wiremock
     ports:
       - 8080:8080
     restart: always
     volumes:
       - ./myfolder/mystuff:/home/wiremock
     command: [--verbose]
```

second way

```
command: --verbose
```

third way

```
command: 
     - --verbose
```

I keep getting the error:

```
wiremock exec: "--verbose": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Comment: the image `wiremock` does not exist on dockerhub. If it's a custom image, you need to show your dockerfile. With `wiremock/wiremock` it would work, see https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-docker/blob/main/docker-entrypoint.sh

Comment: I landed on this question trying to fix a wiremock within kubernetes: I really needed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32302585/3751373
TLDR: you may need the [`Dockerfile`s entrypoint](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-docker/blob/131a39594cf0538ebafc2d69ed44d7169c5dea29/Dockerfile#L55) command in your `command` array as well as the flag

Answer (score 6):

I've set up it in this way:

```
  mocked-services:
    image: wiremock/wiremock:2.33.2
    command: "--global-response-templating --verbose"
```